# jQuery - replacing div background image from URL

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, background

I'm trying to replace div background in several divs from label element (typed URL) and while the code works, it won't push through **$('#urlImage')**.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.first, .second, .third').append("");
  $('#urlImage').change(function(){
    $('.first, .second, .third').css('background-image', $('#urlImage').val());
  });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="urlImage" placeholder="Type image URL">

<div class="first">
</div>
<div class="second">
</div>
<div class="third">
</div>
```

Basically I need whatever is typed to be loaded as a background image.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: check whether the css is being applied properly by inspecting the element,oh and its `jQuery` not `jQuary`

Comment: All is good with css, I can place other things, just not background image (style) in that form. lol, edited, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#urlImage>div').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', $('#urlImage').val());
  });
})
```

Comment: My idea, 
Find all div in side id="urlImage". For each div you will change background-image.

Comment: But that changes div inside #urlImage and I need to change them separately. Thanks for reply!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @BydenProps: Yes of course. 
In this time, my solution is work around.
Please vote me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Dom elements inside a div and iterate through it looking for div elements and add background-image css property to each div with urlImage input's value
This would only work if you already have some value in your input element in order to handle it always you should handle it through keypress or keyup event

**HTML**

```
      <div id="wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="urlImage" placeholder="Type image URL">

       <div class="first">
       </div>
        <div class="second">
         </div>
         <div class="third">
        </div>
       </div>
```

**JS:**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var imageUrl = document.getElementById("#urlImage").value;
    $('#wrapper > div').each(function () {
      this.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');// "this" is the current element in the loop
     });
     })
```

**Edit 1**

```
    (function(){
      $( "#urlImage" ).keyup(function(){
        var imageUrl = document.getElementById("#urlImage").value;
       $('#wrapper > div').each(function () {
        this.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');// "this" is the current element in the loop
       });
       });
       })
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it would work, but I got error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

Comment: I have edited the answer please have a look at it. It was a typo it should be document.getElementById instead of document.getElementbyId

Comment: Ok, typo fixed, now I have: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null